# Not understanding fixtures in ember

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to, for better lack of a term stub out my application's user model using fixtures. I have been following the docs on [fixtures, as well as associated links for model development](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/). The issue is that I keep running  into `cannot GET /user/Administrator` I have used yeoman to generate a ember project, but lets walk through what I have:

**Set up the app**

```
var EW = window.EW = Ember.Application.create();
```

**Setup the fixture (store.js)**

```
EW.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

/* I need a fixture. */
EW.User.FIXTURES = [
    {
       "user":{
          "id":1,
          "first_name":"Adam",
          "email":"adamkylebalan@email.com",
          "last_name":"Balan",
          "user_name": "Administrator",
          "role_names":[
             "Administrator"
          ],
          "blogs":[
             {
                "id":2,
                "title":"Blog Title",
                "posts":[
                   {
                      "id":1,
                      "title":"Something",
                      "content":"Some Content",
                      "tag_names":[
                         "Some Tag",
                         "Other Tag"
                      ],
                      "category_names":[
                         "Some Category",
                         "Another Category"
                      ],
                      "blog_id":2,
                      "comments":[
                         {
                            "id":1,
                            "post_id":1,
                            "author":"Adam",
                            "comment":"This is a valid long comment."
                         }
                      ]
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    }
]
```

**Model**

```
var attr = DS.attr;

// Set up the user model and it's relationships.
EW.User = DS.Model.extend({
    first_name: attr('string'),
    last_name: attr('string'),
    user_name: attr('string'),
    blogs: DS.hasMany('blog'),
    role: DS.hasMany('roles'),

    // Create full names for every one.
    fullName: function(){
        return this.get('first_name') + ' ' + this.get('last_name');
    }.property('first_name', 'last_name')

});
```

**Router**

```
EW.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('user', { path: '/user/:user_name' });
});

EW.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return jQuery.getJSON("/user/" + params.user_name);
    }

    serialize: function(model){
        return { user_name: model.get('user_name') }
    }
});
```

As far as I can tell I have done everything correctly. throws the error:

`Cannot GET /user/Administrator`

and I am not sure if I failed to set something up properly. the console gives me no errors, the ember console wont load because of this error and the network tab is giving me a 404 for `localhost:9000/user/Administrator`

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll want to call `return this.get('store').find('user', params.user_id)` in your model hook:

```
EW.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('user', { path: '/users/:user_id' });
});

EW.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.get('store').find('user', params.user_id);
  }
});
```

Note that it’s `user_id` rather than `user_name`. This is because the fixture adapter is hard coded to find records by their `id` rather than name. I’d suggest using the url-friendly form of the name as the ID.

Comment: When I do that, it screams at me: `Error while loading route: Error: the id property must be defined as a number or string for fixture`

Comment: You may find it’s complainging because it can’t load the related Job and Role.

Comment: Oh, and in your fixture data you don’t need to put the user data inside a `user` key. FIXTURES should be an array of objects containing the user data directly.

Comment: Note you’ll need to define the complementary fixtures on Job and Role for your hasMany relationships to work.